# Table row data become card row

Tags: html, css

My current table data is look like image1 how can make it to become the image2 the data look like card? I tried the border-radius CSS, but it still looks same nothing changes. I think the current data look very messy so I think change to card row data will become better...
[image]
[image]

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table tr {
   border: 2px solid #eee; 
   border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
}
table th, table td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table v-if="items.length >0">
              <thead>
                <th>{{$t('date')}}</th>
                <th>{{$t('description')}}</th>
                <th>{{$t('previousBalance')}}</th>
                <th>{{$t('debit')}}</th>
                <th>{{$t('credit')}}</th>
                <th>{{$t('balance')}}</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody  v-for="(item) in items" :key="item">
                <tr>
                  <td :data-label="$t('date')">{{item.txDate}}</td>
                  <td :data-label="$t('description')">           {{item.txDesc}}</td>  
                  <td :data-label="$t('previousBalance')">{{item.txBalBefore}}</td>
                  <td :data-label="$t('debit')" v-if="item.txAmount <=0">{{ item.txAmount }}</td>
                  <td :data-label="$t('debit')" v-else>0.00</td>
                  <td :data-label="$t('credit')" v-if="item.txAmount > 0">{{item.txAmount}}</td>
                  <td :data-label="$t('credit')" v-else>0.00</td>
                  <td :data-label="$t('balance')">{{item.txBalAfter}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't try your snippets. but please take a look if this is what you are expecting.

```css
body{
  box-sizing: border-box
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:0 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none
}

table td, #customers th {
  padding: 20px;
}

table tr {background-color: #eaeefa;}

table th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #d9dff3;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
td:last-child,
th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Role</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Temitope</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Accountant</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfred</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Designer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bello</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>Painter</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>Architect</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>James</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Manager</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Let me know if you have any questions